# Where to put reusable code?

Tags: theming

I have used Drupal 7 for a while, but am only starting to learn to use the tpl and template.php files. As you would expect, I have become good friends with the documentation, but am still having trouble putting all the pieces together at times.

One thing that I have not figured out how to do, but seems pretty basic, is to create a function in template.php or a custom tpl file (not sure what I need as well as how to do it) that outputs HTML. Let me explain what I mean...

I have created a custom node--content-type.tpl.php. In there, I have put the following code in to replace the normal submitted by information:

```
<?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
  <div class="submitted">
    <div class="created">
      <span>Created by <?php print $node->name; ?> on <?php print format_date($node->created, $type = 'medium'); ?>.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="revised">
      <span>Last revised by <?php print (user_load($node->revision_uid)->name); ?> on <?php print format_date($node->changed, $type = 'medium'); ?>.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I am trying to figure out how to reuse this code in some of my other custom node tpl files without simply cutting and pasting it in. I am obviously missing something basic. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Re-usable template code should ideally be in its own template, backed by its own theme function:

```
function THEME_theme() {
  return [
    'foo_partial' => [
      'variables' => ['node' => NULL],
    ],
  ];
}
```

foo-partial.tpl.php:

```
<div class="submitted">
    <div class="created">
      <span>Created by <?php print $node->name; ?> on <?php print format_date($node->created, $type = 'medium'); ?>.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="revised">
      <span>Last revised by <?php print (user_load($node->revision_uid)->name); ?> on <?php print format_date($node->changed, $type = 'medium'); ?>.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

There are a number of different permutations you could use to actually get that HTML into the node template, here's one of them:

```
function THEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['node']->type == 'page' && $vars['display_submitted']) {
    $vars['submitted_html'] = [
      '#theme' => 'foo_partial',
      '#node' => $vars['node'],
    ];
  }
}
```

node.tpl.php

```
...
<?php
if ($display_submitted && $submitted_html):
  echo render($submitted_html);
endif;
?>
...
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: I ended up having to add "'template' => 'foo-partial'," to the foo_partial array in hook_theme to get it to work. Otherwise all is good. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh yeah, Drupal 7. My brain’s in D8 these days. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be standard across all your nodes, you can create a simple node.tpl.php file that will apply to all node pages.

EDIT: For it to apply to some subset of nodes, check out [Can I use one node template file for multiple content types?](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2011-12-13/can-i-use-one-node-template-file-for-multiple-content) on d.o.

Comment: I understand that. I am trying to use it in some of the content-types and not the other (along with other differences to the code by content-type), again, without having to cut and paste it into each template.

Comment: @kosher sorry, misunderstood - edited to reflect better answer.